# Access arraylist index of "nested" dust.js scope

Tags: dust.js

I pass to my template a object with two properties:

- `Headers` which is an of strings like `['letter 1','letter 2']`.
- `Values` which is an array of array of strings like `[['a','b'],['c','d']]`.

My template looks as follow

```
{#Values}
<tr>
    {#. header=Headers[$idx]}
    <td>{header}: {.}</td>
    {/.}
</tr>
```

But it doesn't work, $idx is the index of `Values` and not index of `Values[...]`.

So what's the right syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem hinges on when dust evaluates values of parameters to a section/partial.
If the value is a constant (param="abc") or a name {param=xyz}, the value of the parameter is evaluated before the context is shifted into the section or partial. That means the value of the parameter is whatever it would be just before the section/partial line.  If the param value is of the form param="{xyz}" then a function is generated that is called in the section or partial to be evaluated. This function will see values in the context of being within the section and any iteration it is doing.  As written, Headers[$idx] will use the $idx value of Values iteration. If you change it to

{#. header="{Headers[$idx]}"}

it will be evaluated within the section and get the $idx value of {#.} iteration.